# How to deploy Mac App Store software to a computer lab?

Tags: macos, mac-app-store

I'm interested in using some Mac App Store software (software that's not available to be licensed separately, such as, for example, Final Cut Pro X) in the computer labs I administer.  What are my options for managing licenses?

Comment: There was some discussion about this on MacEnterprise last month --- http://groups.google.com/group/macenterprise/browse_frm/thread/4097fde68153803 .  Conclusion was that there aren't currently any options beyond convincing the developer to license the software without using the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 1):

Mac App Store software can be installed on up to five machines. One way you could set everything up is to split your computers into groups of five and make an Apple account for each group, then buy Final Cut (or whatever software you want) on each account, set up each group of computers with its account and install Final Cut on all of them.

Comment: Does this license really hold for (obviously) non-private use?

Comment: I don't know: I've never read the license. All I know is that that would probably *work*.